# Sum of odd numbers until reached limit in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

While I was solving a question saying "add odd numbers from 1 to 20", I coded this:

```js
var i, sum=0;
for (i=2; i<=20; i*2){
  sum=sum+i;
}
document.write(sum);
```

When I launched it through a browser, it did not work. However, when I fixed `i*2` into `i+=2`, it worked.

What am I missing? Am I not able to use *(multiplier) in For Loops?

Comment: Why don't you try to `console.log("i is:",i)` in the loop? It's not a problem to multiply i by 2 every time but you don't get the output you expected. Next odd number is `oddNumber +2` not `oddNumber * 2`

Comment: Why are you even trying to use `*`? You've said *"add odd numbers from 1 to 20"* which suggests you want to *add* 2 to `i`, not multiply `i` by `2` each time.

Comment: *"add odd numbers from 1 to 20"* You're missing out `1` by starting `i` at `2`.

Comment: ‘for (i=2; i<=20; i = i*2)’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to add odd numbers from 1 to 20, then you need `i+=2` as the third parameter of the for and need to initialize the variable to 1 to get the correct result:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i += 2) {
    sum += i;
}
```

When you have

> i += 2

2 is added to `i` and the result is stored into `i`. When you tried

```
var i, sum=0;
for (i=2; i<=20; i*2){
  sum=sum+i;
}
```

`i*2` calculates the value which is twice as big as `i`, but it will not change the value of `i`, so this would "work" instead:

```
var i, sum=0;
for (i=2; i<=20; i*=2){
  sum=sum+i;
}
```

where

```
i *= 2
```

not only calculates the value twice as big as `i`, but stores the result into `i` as well. However, even though this will run, the result will not be correct, since you are using the wrong formula.

Also, you can calculate the result without using a `for`:

> 1 + 2 + ... + n = n * (n + 1) / 2

Assuming that n is pair: and since we know that we are "missing" half the numbers and all the pair numbers are bigger exactly with 1 than the previous impair numbers, we can subtract half of the sequence

> n * (n + 1) / 2 - n / 2 = (n * (n + 1) - n) / 2 = (n * (n + 1 - 1)) /
>   2 = n * n / 2

and now we have exactly the double value of what we need, so the final formula is:

```
sum = n * n / 4;
```

Let's make this a `function`

```
function getOddSumUpTo(limit) {
    if (limit % 2) limit ++;
    return limit * limit / 4;
}
```

and then:

```
var sum = getOddSumUpTo(20);
```

Note that we increment limit if it is odd.

Comment: Felicitari for your awesome answer. I also found a similar formula for this type of exercise.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Am vazut-o deja and I have upvoted it.

Comment: Wow, l totally got it. Thank you Lajos !

Comment: @CalebHyun you are welcome. You can accept an answer. I think both mine and Ionut's answer is correct and useful.

Comment: @LajosArpad I don't think your answer is acceptable. Why getOddSumUpTo(21) gave score  100.25? How can sum of odd numbers give score with 0.25?

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski so, there were two problems: 1. I accidentally inversed the logic dependent on limit % 2, 2. The formula only works with pair input, so we increment limit if it is odd (and the result will be therefore correct).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're not updating the value of the `i` in the for `loop`.

> I want add odd numbers from 1 to 20

Then you need to change the initial value of `i` to `1`.

```js
var i, sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i += 2){
  sum += i;
}
document.write(sum);
```

Also, you can find the sum of `odd numbers from 1 to 20` by using a formula.

```js
n = 20;
console.log(n % 2 == 0 ? (n * n)/ 4 : ((n + 1) * (n + 1))/4);
```

Comment: I thought if I just write 'i' in the loop, it will keep updating itself as the number gets multiplied. So, can I understand like this? : every time in a for loop, I need to give a value for each one of them.

Comment: @CalebHyun, in a for loop you have to specify the `counter` and that's leads to the idea we  need to update the value of `i` variable.

Comment: But still this loop adds even numbers and not odd ones :)

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski, sorry, my mistake. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can you just have to do it simillary to what you've written about sum.

You used there `i += 2` and not `i + 2`.

The same way just change `i * 2` to `i *= 2`.

**Here is an working example**

```js
var i, sum = 0;
for (i = 2; i <= 20; i *= 2) {
  console.log(i);
  sum += i;
}
document.write(sum);
```

But a couple of things here.

**First of all** you wrote

> *add odd numbers from 1 to 20*

and in all your examples you use sum on even numbers.

**Secondly**, by multiplying you will not achieve your desired goal (as you can see in a snippet above in a console)

So to actually

> *add odd numbers from 1 to 20*

you should do it like this:

```js
var i, sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i += 2) {
  console.log(i);
  sum += i;
}
document.write(sum);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to add even numbers you still can't use multiplying.

*Why?* Simply because you said yourself that you want a sum of numbers.

So let's say that we start with 2.
If we multiply it by 2 it has the value 4 which is fine.
But now look what happens in the next iteration. Our variable `i` which has the value 4 is multiplied by 2 and now its new value is 8. So what about 6?
Next iteration multiply 8 by 2 and its new value is 16.

Do you see where this is going?

And when you use `i += 2` instead of `i *= 2`?

So if we start with 2 and than we add 2 its new value is 4.
In next iteration we add 2 to 4 and we have 6.
And so on.

If you want to test it, **here is an example with multiplying and adding**.

Pay attention to console logs

```js
var i;

console.log("Multiplying");
for (i = 2; i <= 20; i *= 2) {
  console.log("i value is: " + i);
}

console.log("Adding");
for (i = 2; i <= 20; i += 2) {
  console.log("i value is: " + i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof, sorry the question was to combine even numbers, I wrote wrongly. I wonder in the loop - for (i = 1; i <= 20; i += 2)- I do not know why I should use i+=2 instead of just i*2. I thought i is already defined as 1 (i=1). but why do I need to it like i+=2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever expression in loop header, even this is a valid for loop statement `for (;;)` which simply runs forever (equivalent to `while(true)`).

Problem is that you are not updating the `i` counter in `for (i=2; i<=20; i*2)` so the `i` will stays the same throughout the execution of the loop.
If you change it to for `(i=2; i<=20; i = i*2)` or `for (i=2; i<=20; i *=2)` then it will work.

It is the same as if you did

```js
let i = 1;

i * 2;
console.log(i);

i = i * 2;
console.log(i);
```

The first `i * 2` doesn't update the `i` while the second one does.

You can also translate the for loop into while loop to see the error more clearly.

```
// wrong
let i = 1;
while(i <= 20) {
  i * 2;
  // do something
}

// right
let i = 1;
while(i <= 20) {
  i = i * 2 // or i *= 2
  // do something
}
```

Just a side note, if you wanted to perform sum on more types of sequences efficiently than you could use a generator based approach and write your sum function and describe each type of a sequence with a generator function.

```js
function *generateOdd(start, end) {
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 1) { yield i; }
  }
}

function *generateEven(start, end) {
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) { yield i; }
  }
}

function sumNums(gen, start, end) {
  const generator = gen(start, end);
  let res = 0;

  let item = generator.next();
  while (!item.done) {
    res += item.value;
    item = generator.next();
  }

  return res;
}

console.log(sumNums(generateOdd, 0, 20));
console.log(sumNums(generateEven, 0, 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is this :

```js
let sum = 0;
for(var i = 2; i <= 20; i += 2){
  sum += i;
}
document.write(sum)
```

Another take on this :

```js
// set to n (what you want). Set to n + 1
var N = 21;

// The main driver code create an array from 0-(N-1) and removes all even nums

let a = Array.apply(null, {length: N}).map(Number.call, _ => +_).filter(_=>_%2)

// console.log the array
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* sum of the Odd number using loop */
function sumOfOddNumbers(n){
  let sum= 0;
  for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      if(i % 2 !== 0){
        sum = sum + i;
      }    
  }
  return sum;
}

// 567 = 1+3+5+7+9+11+13+15+17+19+21+23+25+27+29+31+33+35+37+39+41+43+45+47
let n = 47;
let sum = sumOfOddNumbers(47);
alert('sumOfOddNumbers(' + n + ') = ' + sum);
```